# hide and show button for an image is not working randomely in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a simple app for showing an image with a button and hiding that with another button. Button function is running nice when i click once on show and hide but after one click each, both stop responding. Please help and here is the code:-

```
package com.androminor.funcolor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FunActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
Button buttonHide;
ImageView image;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun);
    buttonListener();
}
public void buttonListener() {

    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChange);
    buttonHide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHide);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.golushapng);
        }
    });
    buttonHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.androminor.funcolor.FunActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonChange"
    android:text="@string/Golusha"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="108dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hide"
    android:id="@+id/buttonHide"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonChange"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you've set the image's visibility to invisible when you click the hideButton. You need to make the image visible again.

In your first button's onClick listener, add the following line:

```
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thank you@max59. It worked. Just been wondering, if image was enabled just by the click of button then why i have to use setVisibility. Before i did not use it still the button was working.